# Windows Phone equivalent to Android "tools:text"

Tags: windows-phone

When creating layout in Android I can preview texts and others properties without actually applying the value using tools [attribute](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes). There something like that for Windows Phone ? I want to preview how my layout without change the  Binding properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what the Android attributes do correctly the similar feature to allow fake data in the Xaml designer is design-time attributes. You can apply attributes such as d:DataContext and d:DesignSource to provide preview data in the designer.

See [Displaying Data in the Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx#displaying_data_in_the_designer) in MSDN's data binding overview for example code.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what I needed, although this need much more effort  than tools attribute.